# Pass an Enum and Return a New Class

Tags: java, enums

I was hoping to make a `SceneManager` class to provide limited control over a single active scene with methods like `setActiveScene(Scenes newScene)` where `Scenes` is an enum, `updateScene(double time)` which wraps the update method of an active `Scene`, and `getActiveScene()` to retrieve certain components of the active scene. The hope was that only the `SceneManager` could create new Scenes, and that adding a new possible scene would be as simple as adding to the `Scenes` enum with which class to instantiate. What I had was something like this:

```java
public class SceneManager {
    private static Scene activeScene = null;

    private static void setActiveScene(Scenes newScene) {
        activeScene = newScene.load();
    }

    public enum Scenes {
        START(new StartScene()), MENU(new MenuScene());
    
        private final Scene scene;
    
        Scenes(Scene scene) {
            this.scene = scene;
        }
        
        protected Scene load() { return scene; }
    }
}
```

It sorta worked except that I need the `Scene` to only be initialized when it's set. This setup initializes all the scenes right away and that won't work. I was hoping to find a cleaner solution than a switch statement but I'm not sure how else to make it work now. I tried messing with `Constructor`s but that was getting even messier than the switch and probably far less efficient too.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what is the purpose of the `enum`, but wouldn't this be an ideal place for inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Don't initialise the scenes in their constructors, but with an init method:

```
interface Scene {
  void init();
  ...
}
...
private static void setActiveScene(Scenes newScene) {
  activeScene = newScene.load();
  activeScene.init();
}
```

Don't create the scenes when the `enum` is initialised, only when you load it:

```
public enum Scenes {
  START(StartScene.class), MENU(MenuScene.class);
  private final Class<Scene> sceneClass;
  ...
  protected Scene load() {
    try {
      return sceneClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```